# Convert Object[] result in Matlab Runtime to double[][] array Java

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, matlab-deployment

How do I convert Object[] result in Matlab Runtime to double[][] array Java?
I've tried with  "toDoubleArray" like this:

```
MWNumericArray data1=null;
        MWNumericArray data2=null;
        Object[] result = null;
        Class1 lse = null;
        Object[] hasil;
        try {
            data1=new MWNumericArray(A, MWClassID.DOUBLE);
            data2=new MWNumericArray(target, MWClassID.DOUBLE);
            lse = new Class1();
            result = lse.rekursif_lse(1, data1,data2);
            System.out.println(" "+result[0]);
            MWNumericArray mytemp = (MWNumericArray) result[0];
            double[][] bar =(double[][]) mytemp.toDoubleArray();
            T = bar;
            for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
            for(j=0;j<2;j++){
                System.out.println(" "+T[i][j]);
            }
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception! "+e.toString());}
        finally
        {
         MWArray.disposeArray(data1);
         MWArray.disposeArray(data2);
         MWArray.disposeArray(result);
         lse.dispose();
        }
```

but the output was:

> **> In rekursif_lse (line 11)
>
> 1.0e+45 *
>
> -0.2047
>
> -0.7003
>
> -0.2422
>
> 0.4113
>
> -5.6423
>
> 4.5718
>
> -1.6527
>
> 3.5924
>
> 6.5032
>
> -5.7239
>
> 0.2034
>
> 0.6966
>
> 0.2437
>
> -0.4095
>
> 5.6115
>
> -4.5425
>
> 1.6626
>
> -3.5839
>
> -6.4737
>
> ### 5.4594
>
> 2.0467650070969492E44
>
> Exception! java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

It can be seen that the Matlab Compiler Runtime is worked but I can't input the "result" to "T" which:

```
double T[][]=new double[20][1];
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the array indexes: you have a two dimensional array with the measurements [20][1], but in the print loop you've put:

```
 for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
     for(j=0;j<2;j++){
          System.out.println(" "+T[i][j]);
     }
 }
```

Which means you're traversing an array of dimensions [20][2]. In order to not go beyond the dimensions of your array, simply remove the for loop for J:

```
for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
    System.out.println(" "+T[i][0]);
}
```

Because the two dimensional array has in fact one dimension and contains 20 elements - the second coordinate is always 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I mean that I want to input the Object[] into the T[][]. But I've done with it through change the Object[] itu MWArray and then call the getData() method. After that I use the for loop to take the data. Once again, thank you so much!!! @Assafs

Comment: No problem, I hope I helped a bit. If you have another question about this - could you perhaps edit the question above and I'll try to help a bit more.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. But I've already solved it by getdata() method.
Thankyou so much!

Comment: If everything is solved and you all done - would you mind accepting my answer, by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer, making it green?